# What would be a user friendly message when the user has a slow internet connection?

Tags: error-message, internet

We provide some big data slides for free for our users, but when their internet connection is slow we have to put a message there because due to the large amount of data it takes a while to load.

Comment: Those websites that do this offer content with fewer images etc. if your slides are big anyway, what action could you possibly take?

Comment: Are you using AJAX?

Comment: Lazy loading comes to mind - load the critical content first - then the next most important and so on. If you can, show a load meter to give the user some idea of how much is loaded so they have some idea of long it will take. Warn them before hand: "this may take a while to load on slower connections".

Comment: Can you provide a status bar?

Answer (score 2):

People fret very easily when there's any sort of delay while loading a webpage.

Now, the reason behind it could be **slow internet, poor indexing, improper format, loss of data packets, transaction failure, size of data, faulty request ...**

The list could go on ...

So, here's what you need to keep in mind:

- Empathy goes a long way
- Remember they are humans and are **frustrated**
- Stay positive!
- Humor is great defense mechanism :P

Examples:
[image: Connectivity delay message 1]
[image: Connectivity slow message 1]
[image: Connectivity slow message 2]